# list to match another nested list

Tags: nested-lists

second list sorted according to the first

`[['E', 'E', 'C], ['B', 'C', 'A'], ['E', 'B', 'F'], ['D', 'F', 'E']]`

Comment: What's the reasoning behind `['E', 'F', 'D']` to `['D', 'F', 'E']`?

Comment: it's not clear what it is you're even trying to do.  Are you trying to detect which direction to sort each of the other lists, either ascending or descending?  If that's the case we could say your sample should be descending, but the sort order of the other lists in your "after" example is arbitrary at best.

Answer (score 2):

```
ref_list = ['c','b','a']
# sort [1,2,3] according to ref_list... viz: ['c','a','b'] => [3,1,2]
ordering = sorted(range(len(ref_list)), key=lambda i: ref_list[i])
for j in range(len(list2)):
  list2[j] = [list2[j][i] for i in ordering]
```

Comment: I'll up-vote your answer because it's way better than mine. Thank you because today I've learned something!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some quick code I made, it works but it may need some refactoring:

```
def getListIndexes(some_list):
    return [x for x in enumerate(some_list)]

list1 = [['C', 'B', 'A']]
list2 = [['C', 'E', 'E'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['F', 'B', 'E'], ['E', 'F', 'D']]

values_before_1 = getListIndexes(list1[0])
values_after_1 = getListIndexes(list(sorted(list1[0])))

mapping = dict.fromkeys(list(range(len(list1[0]))))
for item in values_before_1:
    before, then = [(item[0],x[0]) for i, x in enumerate(values_after_1) if item[1]==x[1]][0]
    mapping[then] = before

results = [[None, None, None] for l in range(len(list2))]
for i, item in enumerate(list2):
    values = getListIndexes(item)
    for j in range(len(item)):
        results[i][mapping[j]] = list2[i][j]

print "[*] list1 with content: {} has been sorted and now is like: {}\n".format(list1[0], sorted(list1[0]))
print "[*] list2 with content:\n\n{}\n".format(list2)
print "...has been sorted based on list1 sorting and now looks like this...\n"
print results
```

**Output:**

```
[*] list1 with content: ['C', 'B', 'A'] has been sorted and now is like: ['A', 'B', 'C']

[*] list2 with content:

[['C', 'E', 'E'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['F', 'B', 'E'], ['E', 'F', 'D']]

...has been sorted based on list1 sorting and now looks like this...

[['E', 'E', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['E', 'B', 'F'], ['D', 'F', 'E']]
```

Comment: @Lcallan, my pleasure. Please don't forget accepting my answer if it helped you solve the problem :)